# Website looks OK in IE9, but not in Firefox, IE8 and IE7

Tags: website-design

i have a problem with my site http://www.cyprusproperty-4sale.com/123456789.asp
it looks OK in IE9 but not in Firefox, IE8 & IE7.
Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Looks fine to me, can you be clearer about the problem?

Comment: just above the main picture i get a small gap in IE 7&8, a bigger gap in Firefox

Comment: Normally these get migrated to StackOverflow. But without more to go one they would close this there so I didn't bother migrating it. before asking your question there yourself, be sure to offer more information as to your actual problem and what solutions you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the height's of the table cells (`<td></td>`) properly with css or convert to a `<div>` based layout.

The best place for these questions is stackoverflow.com